# Where is the list of Firefox' MD5 hashes?

Tags: firefox

In order to deploy firefox I would like to check the MD5, but cannot find it anywhere. I have searched the web for the MD5 of 49.0.2.

**Attempt to solve the issue**

1. I have found [this](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/3.6.13/) for version 3.6, but when I change the value to 49.0.2 the page is not found. The 3.6 contains the MD5SUMS
2. I have found [another site](https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/49.0.2/linux-x86_64/en-US/) that contains the tar.bz2, but no MD5 overview.

Comment: You realize there’s a [..](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) link...? :D

Comment: They're SHA512 now: http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/49.0.2/ -- MD5 is best avoided nowadays.

Comment: @DanielB Yes, but not for 49.0.2

Comment: The .. link takes you to the parent directory. There’s of course a folder for 49.0.2. You tried to manually create the URL and probably forgot the mandatory `/` at the end.

Comment: @DanielB You are right (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the right place, but instead of just changing the number the best thing to do is click the ".." at the top of the list to go up a directory, then scroll down to the right version. It's more reliable and shows you everything.

49.0.2 is at https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/49.0.2/

There is a SHA512SUMS file in there which should be the hash file, MD5 is considered insecure as it is subject to hash collisions https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security

Answer (score 3):

Mozilla does not provide MD5 hashes anymore due to their *insecurity* – MD5 has been considered 'broken' for several years now, due to its near complete lack of collision resistance.

As you can see in http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/49.0.2/, they provide SHA-512 hashes instead (along with a PGP signature). Additionally, the .exe installers are signed using Authenticode certificates, which Windows can verify natively.